# Можно ли объединить перегруженные функции?

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, function-overloading

Имеется 6 функций абcолютно одинакового содержания

```
void func(int a, string* b);
void func(char a, string* b);
void func(float a, string* b);
void func(long a, string* b);
void func(short a, string* b);
void func(double a, string* b);
```

Можно ли как-нибудь объединить их не дублируя тело функций для каждой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имеете в виду? Шаблоны?

```
template<typename T>
void func(T a, string* b);
```